# xslt nested for-each with comma separated list

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have xml file with list of hobby as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
  <user>
    <fname>somename</fname>
    <hobbies>
      <hobby>Movie</hobby>
      <hobby>Trekking</hobby>
    </hobbies>
  </user>
</users>
```

Xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="users/user">
          <h2>
            <xsl:value-of select="fname" />
          </h2>
          <h3>Hobbies :</h3>
          <xsl:for-each select="hobbies">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text> , </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here i used

```
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text> , </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
```

to generate commas in between the list of hobbies

But the values are displayed without comma.

I am testing this on http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/'s tryit editor.

Whats wrong here? What should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo, I think: `<xsl:for-each select="hobbies/hobby">`

**Update**:

Correct XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="users/user">
                    <h2>
                        <xsl:value-of select="fname" />
                    </h2>
                    <h3>Hobbies :</h3>
                    <xsl:for-each select="hobbies/hobby">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                            <xsl:text> , </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>somename</h2>
    <h3>Hobbies :</h3>Movie , Trekking</body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of  <xsl:value-of select="." /> ? No it doesn't work.

Comment: @gt_ebuddy, No. Instead of `<xsl:for-each select="hobbies">`

Comment: It is still not working(even the list is not displayed). Did you tried  my code? I want to mention that : In my original code, the hobbies [Movie Trekking] are displayed but without comma.